# How to Drop pins on multiple locations mapkit swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I am trying to add the pins to the map using the string array. but it display only one pin does not display second pin on the map.

```
func getDirections(enterdLocations:[String])  {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    // array has the address strings
    for (index, item) in enterdLocations.enumerated() {
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(item, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if((error) != nil){
            print("Error", error)
        }
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {

            let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate

            let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
            dropPin.coordinate = coordinates
            dropPin.title = item
            self.myMapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
            self.myMapView.selectAnnotation( dropPin, animated: true)
   }
    })
    }

}
```

and my calling function

```
@IBAction func findNewLocation()
{
    var someStrs = [String]()
    someStrs.append("6 silver maple court brampton")
    someStrs.append("shoppers world brampton")
    getDirections(enterdLocations: someStrs)
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get one pin back because you allocated just one `let geocoder = CLGeocoder()` so just move that into the `for` loop and it will work like so:

```
func getDirections(enterdLocations:[String])  {
    // array has the address strings
    var locations = [MKPointAnnotation]()
    for item in enterdLocations {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(item, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if((error) != nil){
                print("Error", error)
            }
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {

                let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate

                let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
                dropPin.coordinate = coordinates
                dropPin.title = item
                self.myMapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
                self.myMapView.selectAnnotation( dropPin, animated: true)

                locations.append(dropPin)
                //add this if you want to show them all
                self.myMapView.showAnnotations(locations, animated: true)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I added the locations `var locations` array that will hold all of your annotations so you can show them all with `self.myMapView.showAnnotations(locations, animated: true)`...so remove that if not needed

Comment: Thanks . can you help me to draw the route between pins which are in the array.

Comment: Take a look at something like: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-find-directions-using-mkmapview-and-mkdirectionsrequest